# Laravel 5.1 How to send email verification email after registration?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, user-registration, email-verification

I need users to verify their email address after registration. I have confirmation_code and confirmed fields in users table. How can I send an email after a user registration?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough; I think you ask asking...  "how do I fire an action after a route is called"

Answer (score 8):

You need a normal blade template being the body

```
Mail::send('emails.reminder', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {
    $m->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Your Reminder!');
});
```

In just place a the `confirmation_code` in the email and define a route, e.g.
    mypage.com/emailverification/1389734jhikdfsjkb1234908adkb

When the user vists the link you check the database for this entry and set the status of the registration to completed.

For more information check http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail#sending-mail

For a detailed tutorial check: http://bensmith.io/email-verification-with-laravel

Comment: Thanks, but I like to use the default auth controller

Comment: You can still use the default auth controller. Just put the mail call in the `create` function